# Actual employee working hours from payroll system?

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am working on a project which involves a payroll system for Employees. My main goal is to retrieve the actual work hours for each employee, however I am a bit confused about how I should proceed with the data I have been given. The database I am using is non-relational and it is used to calculate the financial transactions for the company involved. I'm supposed to build a BI-solution using staging tables, dimensions and a data warehouse.

These are the main tables I have to work with:

- Timetable
- Employee
- Transaction
- Deviation

I have timetables in the database which will give me the actual schedule for each employee - in hours. So calculating the hours they are supposed to work is no problem. In transaction I can see how much each employee earns and in deviation I can see if any abnormalities occur - for example if an employee is ill or on holiday. It also states how much is added and deducted to the monthly salary (it also states unit count).

My theory is that I use the transaction/deviation database and compare the results to the actual work schedule - this way I will know if the employee has worked more or less than planned.

Am I on the right track or is there another way of doing this? 
*I have just started with BI so I appreciate any help I can get!*

Comment: this seems you are in correct path.. with this database i think you have to go like this only.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you are on the right path, but really you should be confirming the plan with a data expert familiar with the payroll database.

To make that simple, dummy up some results in Excel first (say pick a random person from the database) and do the calculations to get the actual hours. Take that to the data expert and get them to confirm if this is correct, or perhaps there are exceptions where this business rule does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will work on this today and do as you suggested!